# How to change a single cell name within a shapefile dataframe in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I'm working with election data for Mozambique. I am currently mapping voter turnout and party dominance. I have two separate dataframes: the shapefile in order to plot the map using the sf package and the datatframe with the voter turnout etc.

I managed to solve the issue of accents in both dataframes using iconv but I discovered that some districts are name differently in the shapefile compare to the voter df.

For example: Xai_Xai (a district in the province of Gaza) is named Cidade de Xai_Xai in the shapefile but just Xai_Xai in the voter df. I'd like the latter, so I want to change that cell name to "Xai_Xai". Here is what I've tried. The column was a factor so I changed it to a character, not sure if that was the right thing to do?

```
summary(moz_dist)

   Shape_Leng      Shape_Area          ADM2_PT            ADM2_PCODE          ADM1_PT  
 Min.   :0.114   Min.   :0.0006967   Length:159         MZ0101 :  1   Nampula     :23  
 1st Qu.:2.708   1st Qu.:0.2053424   Class :character   MZ0102 :  1   Zambezia    :23  
 Median :3.753   Median :0.3722152   Mode  :character   MZ0103 :  1   Niassa      :19  
 Mean   :3.637   Mean   :0.4216331                      MZ0104 :  1   Cabo Delgado:17  
 3rd Qu.:4.737   3rd Qu.:0.5841029                      MZ0105 :  1   Tete        :15  
 Max.   :7.797   Max.   :1.4952281                      MZ0106 :  1   Gaza        :14  
                                                        (Other):153   (Other)     :48  
   ADM1_PCODE       ADM0_EN          ADM0_PT    ADM0_PCODE      date           
 MZ07   :23   Mozambique:159   Moçambique:159   MZ:159     Min.   :2019-04-02  
 MZ11   :23                                                1st Qu.:2019-04-02  
 MZ08   :19                                                Median :2019-04-02  
 MZ01   :17                                                Mean   :2019-04-02  
 MZ10   :15                                                3rd Qu.:2019-04-02  
 MZ02   :14                                                Max.   :2019-04-02  
 (Other):48                                                                    
    validOn                    geometry      dist0          
 Min.   :2019-06-07   MULTIPOLYGON :159   Length:159        
 1st Qu.:2019-06-07   epsg:4326    :  0   Class :character  
 Median :2019-06-07   +proj=long...:  0   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :2019-06-07                                         
 3rd Qu.:2019-06-07                                         
 Max.   :2019-06-07
```

"dist0" is the column with all the district names (without accents). The row is number 36.

```
moz_dist[36, moz_dist$dist0 == "Cidade De Xai-Xai"] <- "Xai_Xai" 

Error in if (jj <= nvars) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

moz_dist$dist0[36 , moz_dist$dist0 == "Cidade De Xai-Xai"] <- "Xai_Xai"

Error in moz_dist$dist0[36, moz_dist$dist0 == "Cidade De Xai-Xai"] <- "Xai_Xai" : 
incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

How do I change the name of that cell?

Comment: `moz_dist$dist0[36] <- "Xai_Xai" `?

Comment: @symbolrush seems like I was overthinking everything! Thank you that worked!